# Is this an incorrect use of interfaces?

Tags: c#, interface, factory

Take the following example, I have multiple 'Integration' classes that inherit from the same 'IChannelIntegration' interface.

```
public interface IChannelIntegration
{

}

public class IntegrationA : IChannelIntegration
{

}

public class IntegrationB : IChannelIntegration
{

}

public IChannelIntegration CreateIntegration(string letter)
{
   if(letter = "A")
   {
     return new IntegrationA();
   }
   else if (letter = "B")
   {
     return new IntegrationB();
   }
   else
   {
     return null;
   }
}
```

One of my integrations provides some functionality that other integrations don't. I need a way of calling this functionality on the IChannelIntegration object returned from the CreateIntegration function.

I created the following collection of classes for dealing with these custom IntegrationFeatures. The IntergrationFeature interface is what all features would derive from.

```
public interface IIntegrationFeature {}

public interface ICustomLogic : IIntegrationFeature 
{
  void DoSomething() {}
} 

//Provides a concrete implementation of the logic.
public class CustomLogic : ICustomLogic 
{
  public void DoSomething() {}
}
```

Another interface was then created that would attach to Integration classes to support that the integration provides custom functionality.

```
public interface ISupportsFeature<T>  where T : Interfaces.IIntegrationFeature
{
    T GetFeature();
}
```

It would be implemented as followed;

```
public class IntegrationC : IChannelIntegration, ISupportsFeature<ICustomLogic>
{
    public ICustomLogic GetFeature()
    {
        return new CustomLogic ();
    }
}
```

So that would be how you'd give the Integration it's specific logic and then you'd call it using the following;

```
public static IIntegrationFeature GetIntegrationFeature<IIntegrationFeature>()
        where IIntegrationFeature : Interfaces.IIntegrationFeature
    {
        IIntegrationFeature integrationFeature = null;

        IChannelIntegration service = CreateIntegration();

        //Attempt to cast the integration too determine if it supports the Integration Feature.
        ISupportsFeature<IIntegrationFeature> supportsFeature = service as ISupportsFeature<IIntegrationFeature>;

        if(supportsFeature != null)
        {
            integrationFeature = supportsFeature.GetFeature();
        }

        return integrationFeature;
    }

public void TestMethod()
{
    ICustomLogic customLogic = GetIntegrationFeature<ICustomLogic>();
    if (customLogic != null)
    {
        customLogic.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I'm unsure how I feel on this implementation, part of me thinks I'm massively over complicating the situation but I also think it's quite easy to use as many of my integrations will require custom logic providing for them.

Another issue is that if an integration provides multiple IntegrationFeatures you'll have to explicitly call the interface function due to them having the same GetFeature name, which could cause more confusion for other developers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for a code review. The code works, there is no specific problem to solve.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't aware there was a code review section.

Comment: @Eritey: see: [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I think this `public class ICustomLogic : IIntegrationFeature 
{
  void DoSomething() {}
}` meant to be an interface and not a class,

Comment: This is not about a code-review (don't post it there) but about a design. Maybe for Programmers but I'm not voting to close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start from top to bottom, from your need to the implementation.

From what I see you need to access at runtime a feature provided by an integration created by a certain system from a given value. So your first actors would be

```
interface IIntegrationFeature {}
```

and something that would provide you this feature

```
interface IIntegratedSystem
{
  T GetFeature<T>(string integrationType) where T : IIntegrationFeature;
}
```

A client of this setup would be using the actors like this

```
IIntegratedSystem system = .... // system implementation

T feature = system.GetFeature<T>("Which integration type?");

if (feature != null)
{
    //the feature exists and I'm using it
}
```

The `IIntegratedSystem` implementation's responsibility is to provide the `IIntegrationFeature` from an existing `IChannelIntegration` chosen or created at real time. You considered to inform any client that an `IChannelIntegration` implementation has implemented a feature by implementing the `ISupportFeature<IIntegrationFeature>`. What happens when the integration has about 20 features? You will have a class which implements the integration interface itself and another 20 `ISupports` interfaces. How do you add another feature? You modify the class by adding this new `ISupports<INewFeature>` violating the Single Responsibility Principle. And you don't need to know at compile time that an integration fulfills a certain feature, since the client may or may not use it. Basically `IChannelIntegration` sounds more like a **composite** of integrations which should be able to give an `IIntegrationFeature` and thus the `IChannelIntegration` would have a definition similar to `IIntegratedSystem`

```
interface IChannelIntegration 
{
    T GetFeature<T>() where T : IIntegrationFeature;
}
```

The way how you build the implementation `IChannelIntegration` depends on you but I prefer to let the creation of features on the root of your application. Mine would be like this

```
class ChannelIntegration : IChannelIntegration
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IIntegrationFeature> features;
    public ChannelIntegration()
    {
        features = new Dictionary<Type, IIntegrationFeature>();
    }
    public void RegisterFeature<T>(IIntegrationFeature feature) where T:IIntegrationFeature
    {
        features.Add(typeof(T), feature);
    }
    public T GetFeature<T>() where T : IIntegrationFeature
    {
        IIntegrationFeature feature = features.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out feature) ? feature : null;
        return (T)feature;
    }
}
```

The `ChannelIntegration` class maintains the features list. You use `RegisterFeature` to add more features and to make sure is a feature, you constrain them to implement the `IIntegrationFeature` interface. So when you add a new feature you don't change the `ChannelIntegration` class, you use it.

The `IIntegratedSystem` will access a feature from `IChannelIntegration` based on a runtime values. This asks, as you said, to use an **Abstract Factory**. This would look like

```
interface IChannelIntegrationFactory 
{
    IChannelIntegration CreateIntegration(string integrationType);
}
```

The `IIntegratedSystem` will use this factory to create the `IChannelIntegration` and to achieve this I would use the constructor injection mechanism.

```
   class IntegratedSystem : IIntegratedSystem
{
    private IChannelIntegrationFactory integrationFactory;
    public IntegratedSystem(IChannelIntegrationFactory integrationFactory)
    {
        this.integrationFactory = integrationFactory;
    }
    public T GetFeature<T>(string integrationType) where T: IIntegrationFeature
    {
        T integrationFeature = default(T);
        IChannelIntegration integration = integrationFactory.CreateIntegration(integrationType);
        if (integration != null)
        {
            integrationFeature = (T)integration.GetFeature<T>();    
        }
        return integrationFeature;
    }
}
```

Now the `IntegratedSystem` class is using the `IChannelIntegrationFactory` to create an `IChannelIntegration` based on the runtime value and then it will retrieve from it the implemented `IIntegrationFeature` if any.

What we need now is to implement this factory which will create the `IChannelIntegration`s with their `IIntegrationFeature`s

Let's create first a new feature

```
interface ICustomFeature : IIntegrationFeature {}

class CustomFeature : ICustomFeature
{       
}
```

And based on this the Abstract Factory implementation is like

```
class ChannelIntegrationFactory : IChannelIntegrationFactory
{
    public IChannelIntegration CreateIntegration(string integrationType)
    {
        // use integrationType to decide witch IChannelIntegration to use
        IChannelIntegration integration = new ChannelIntegration();
        integration.RegisterFeature<ICustomFeature>(new CustomFeature());

        return integration;
    }
}
```

We created here a `ChannelIntegration` with its single feature. Sure you can have multiple paths like you started where you create different `IChannelIntegrations` with their own `ICustomFeature`s and retrieve the one based on `integrationType` parameter.

So how you consume this?

```
    IIntegratedSystem system = new IntegratedSystem(new ChannelIntegrationFactory());
    ICustomFeature customFeature = system.GetFeature<ICustomFeature>("Which Integration?");
    if (customFeature != null)
    {
        //use this custom feature

    }
    else
    {
        // that's OK, will wait until is registered.
    }
```

You want to add a new feature? Register it in the Abstract Factory implementation.

***`So would you expect to create a new abstract factory of type ChannelIntegrationFactory for each different type of ChannelIntegration?`***

No. The factory picks one of from a list of concrete implementations. Here is one example

```
class ChannelIntegrationFactory : IChannelIntegrationFactory
{
    public IChannelIntegration CreateIntegration(string integrationType)
    {
        IChannelIntegration integration = null;
        switch (integrationType)
        {
            case "MobileIntegration":
                integration = new ChannelIntegration();
                integration.Register<ITapGestureTrack>(new TapGestureTrack());
                break;
            case "DesktopIntegration":
                integration = new ChannelIntegration();
                integration.Register<IClickTrack>(new ClickTracker());
                integration.Register<ILargeImagesProvider>(new LargeImagesProvider());
                break;
        }
        return integration;
    }
}
```

You can even make the `ChannelIntegration` as abstract and create specialized integrations:

```
 class MobileIntegration : ChannelIntegration
    {
       public MobileIntegration()
       {
            Register<ITapGestureTrack>(new TapGestureTrack());
       }
    }

    class DesktopIntegration : ChannelIntegration
    {
       public DesktopIntegration()
       {
            Register<IClickTrack>(new ClickTracker());
            Register<ILargeImagesProvider>(new LargeImagesProvider());
       }
    }
```

And the Abstract Factory becomes

```
class ChannelIntegrationFactory : IChannelIntegrationFactory
    {
        public IChannelIntegration CreateIntegration(string integrationType)
        {
            IChannelIntegration integration = null;
            switch (integrationType)
            {
                case "MobileIntegration":
                    integration = new MobileIntegration();
                    break;
                case "DesktopIntegration":
                    integration = new DesktopIntegration();
                    break;
            }
            return integration;
        }
    }
```

Just see this class as your system's bootstrap class. This is the only class which creates integrations with the features. Btw this is how you can easily enable Dependency Inversion, using your preferred IoC.
[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wosLJu)

Comment: I'd considered doing something like this but couldn't figure out a good method of telling the ChannelIntegration what features it supports.

So would you expect to create a new abstract factory of type ChannelIntegrationFactory for each different type of ChannelIntegration?

You're example was very clear and thought out, thank you very much.

Comment: I think I prefer the second solution where the Features are added in the constructor, We have over 15 integrations so managing them all in a single class could get rather messy. What does IoC stand for also? I've not seen that mentioned before.

Comment: See topics like Dependency Inversion and Inversion of Control. If you create so many objects of different types seems like a good candidate.